# Wpf public property as ConvertParameter

Tags: wpf

ConvertParameter as public propoerty

I would add a parameter to my converter "FormatValues". This is the XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Points}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:DataPointViewModel}">
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Title"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Value"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Series.Title}" Margin="2,1" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Y, Converter={StaticResource FormatValues}}" Margin="2,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource fntRoboto}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My code behind:

```
public partial class ViewerStatisticsTT : IChartTooltip
    {
        public bool Antani { get; set; }

        public ViewerStatisticsTT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;            
        }
    }
```

The istance of my class in another one is this:

```
<userControls:ViewerStatisticsTT Antani="True" />
```

Basically I want take the value of "Antani" parameter and use it as ConvertParameter. Any hints?

Comment: That would require to bind the ConverterParameter to the Antani property, which isn't possible. Use a MultiBinding instead.

Comment: We can't find out the relationship between your sample class and your `ItemTemplate`, and it's important for us to figure out a solution such as designing a bindable converter.

Comment: we are guessing what you need here! my guess is that each item does not have `Antani` but their parent has. correct? and you want the children to bind to `Antani` which is in an upper level than them.